# Android APK artifact name with respective ABI architecture

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to extract and use the architecture of the artifact to compose the output file name:

```
void defineDefaultVariantsAPK(String appName) {
    defineVariantsAPK({ variant, output ->
        def versionName = variant.versionName
        def versionCode = "-(${variant.versionCode}"
        def buildLetter = variant.buildType.name == "release" ? "-R" : "-D"
        def flavor = variant.productFlavors.size() > 0 ? "-${variant.productFlavors[0].name}" : ""
        def architecture = "-" + output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)

        "v${versionName}${versionCode}${buildLetter}${flavor}${architecture}--${appName}.apk"
    })
}

void defineVariantsAPK(Closure nameBuild) {
    android {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File((String) output.outputFile.parent, nameBuild(variant, output))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for some reason many posts says that that is the solution, but my gradle fails on:

```
> Could not get unknown property 'com' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

I've tried to use import:

```
unable to resolve class com.android.build.OutputFile
```

configuration:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3
Gradle version 3.5
```

So I really wonder, what am I doing different that it doesn't work?

Comment: Where did you define this function? Try to move it you your `app/build.gradle` file as that is where buildscript is and gradle loads classes from it into classpath.

Comment: by the gods... I add this line "import com.android.build.OutputFile" and it just disappears in front of my eyes... my Mac is possessed...

Comment: @blazsolar, please post an answer so I can reward you, as you've brought me a step closer to the solution :)

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So following @blazsolar suggestion I've moved the method to the app build gradle file, the move itself was not the solution, when I tried to add the import:

```
import com.android.build.OutputFile
```

for some reason the IDE (Android studio) has decided to delete the import..

but once I've this import:

```
import com.android.build.OutputFile.FilterType
```

it was just fine!
but that is not the end of it... I want the method to be in a common gradle file, that all my project can reuse.

once I've added the last import to the common gradle file... the import figging disappeared again..

I am left with yet [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859821/android-studio-import-class-disappear-from-gradle-file)

---

update:

So I've update Android plugin and gradle version to 3.0.1 and 4.1 respectively, and now... things have change.. now there is no

```
com.android.build.OutputFile.FilterType
```

Now you need to use:

```
com.android.build.VariantOutput.ABI
```

Just in case anyone wonder...

Answer (score 3):

Beggining with Gradle 3.0.0 you can do it like this:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def appName = "AppName_"
        def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name
        def architecture = output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)
        def newName
        if (buildType == 'debug') {
            newName = "${appName}debug_${defaultConfig.versionName}_${architecture}.apk"
        } else {
            newName = "${appName}release_${defaultConfig.versionName}_${architecture}.apk"
        }
        outputFileName = newName
    }
}
```

*put this in your module(app) build.gradle file.

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me with gradle 3+ for android

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def architecture = output.filters[0].identifier
        outputFileName = "myapp-${architecture}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This is the only one that works for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Where did you define this function? Try to move it you your app/build.gradle file as that is where buildscript is and gradle loads classes from it into classpath.

Comment: I have defined this function in a common gradle file, to be used to generally define the names of my artifacts: https://github.com/nu-art/dev-tools/blob/master/gradle/utils.gradle