# Android studio, import class disappear from gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This is a little weird, I have a gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    apply from: '../dev-tools/gradle/common-cyborg-app.gradle'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nu.art.cyborg.demo"
    }

    defineDefaultVariantsAPK("dev-project")
}
```

when I add the following import:

```
import com.android.build.OutputFile
```

the import just disappears.. really there is no other way to describe it.
I've cleared caches and restarted, cleaned the project and nothing.

Every time I paste the line, after a few seconds it is "magically" gone...

Anyone?

---

Update so the accepted answer worked for a while (a day) and once studio crashed, it stopped working... I really don't know why and I wasted too much time on it that I don't really care, BUT I did manage to workaround the problem, [take a look](https://github.com/nu-art/dev-tools/blob/master/gradle/utils.gradle), I pass the filter from the app build.gradle file

Comment: Make sure that you are editing the real `build.gradle` file -- the one in your module's directory -- not some merged one in `build/`. I usually see the "make a change and it vanishes" problem with [the manifest](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/04/08/why-cant-edit-manifest-android-studio.html), but in theory it could happen with `build.gradle`, I think.

Comment: I know what you mean, the error leading to the manifest in the build is extremely confusing... and I am definitely editing the correct build.gradle file.. also gradle files should not be added to the build output folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio will remove unussed imports from your gradle files. When you paste it in you are not ussing that import so it removes it. Yea I know, it is silly.

What you should do is first use the class with fully classified name and then add import later.

Comment: so for some reason, it seemed to have worked for a while, and after Studio crashed it stopped working, please take a look at the solution I've found I pass the FilterType.ABI from the top most build.gradle